# LEAN: Proving f(x) is non-negative implies f(x+a) is non-negative

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

Suppose `u` is a non-negative function `ℝ → ℝ`. Let `a : ℝ`. It follows that the translation `v : ℝ → ℝ : x ↦ u(x+a)` is non-negative as well. The goal is proving this in lean.

Here is what I have done so far

```
import data.real.basic

def is_bounded (u : ℝ → ℝ) : Prop :=
∀ (x : ℝ), 0 ≤ u(x)

def T (u : ℝ → ℝ) (a : ℝ) : (ℝ → ℝ) :=
λ x, u(x + a)
```

This defines boundedness as being positive (yea I reduced this to a simpler case after spending several hours.) I also defined the translation. Here is my attempt so far:

```
theorem bounded_is_T_invariant (u : ℝ → ℝ) (a : ℝ) (has : is_bounded u) : 
is_bounded (T u a) :=
begin
    intros x,
    unfold T,
    let y : ℝ := x + a,
    have y : ℝ,
    sorry
end
```

Clearly I next want to just substitute `x+a` for `y`, show `y` is real, and be done with it. Thanks.

Comment: Try `apply has` after the `unfold T` (or even before it!).

Comment: Amazing! I somehow forgot I had named that assumption anything. It only worked if `apply has` comes after `unfold T` though.

Comment: I interpret `have y : ℝ` as an attempt to prove that `y` is real. But you already told Lean that `y` is real on the line above it. In fact, you can not prove that some term `y` has type `Y` (e.g. `ℝ`) in Lean. That's a fact of life in type theory. Every term has a type. You can prove properties of the terms. But the type judgment is not one of them. That's an *a priori* that is baked into the system.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for clarifying. My earlier attempt was to define y = x + a and then prove y was real. In other words that R is closed under addition. But I guess that was not needed

Comment: This is a fundamental difference between type theory and set theory. If you want to know more about type theory, I suggest reading the first chapter of the HoTT book. It is very accessible for people with a math background.

Comment: `real.add` (the function with notation `+`) is *by definition* a function which takes in two reals and outputs a real. So y is real by definition -- `real` is the type of `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by commenter.

```
theorem bounded_is_T_invariant (u : ℝ → ℝ) (a : ℝ) (has : is_bounded u) : 
is_bounded (T u a) :=
begin
    intros x,
    unfold T,
    apply has,
end
```